# What's the best way of getting each item from an array in order?

Tags: javascript

I am currently building a quiz based on a code that I've found online, tweaking a couple things, and this specific line it grabs the quiz questions from the array using Math.random to randomize the questions:

```
getNewQuestion = () => {
    questionCounter++;
    const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuesions.length);
    currentQuestion = availableQuesions[questionIndex];
    question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;
}
```

Comment: your question title highly deviates from the question content...

Comment: Sorry, I was editing it.

Comment: Just edited it, I think the question is clear now.

Comment: If you want them in order, you just need to iterate from 0 to n - 1.  No Math.random at all

Comment: seems that you are new to programming in general, follow @Taplar advice

Comment: aight thanks guys, sorry for not explaining it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is keep track of the current question index, and increment it as you grab questions. Similar to your questionCounter keep track of questionIndex globally and only increment it when you are grabbing a new question from the bank.

To grab from the bank all you need to do is `availableQuestions[questionIndex]` as you have, and you could even combine the incrementation and grabbing like this

`availableQuestions[questionIndex++]`

just make to define `questionIndex` globally and initialize it at `0`.

Comment: I implemented it and it starts from the first question just like it should but it when I go for the next one goes straight to the last and it does not end after all. Do I need to clarify a break point some how for this not to happen?

Comment: Just noticed my mistake, I was still using splice since I need not to repeat the randomized questions, after deleting it started working the way it should.   Thanks a lot for the reply.